# regex for one character or another?

Tags: regex, grep

I'm searching for a regex code which lists all the lines that contain an a OR an i.
I tryed this:

```
grep -E '[(a|i)]{1}' testFile.txt
```

but this gives me the words containing a or i and words that contain a en i.
What's wrong?

Comment: what if you try .*(a|i).*

Comment: For the record, the regex for "a or i (or both)" is simply `[ai]` -- `grep` will report a match anywhere on a line, so you don't need leading or trailing wildcards.

Comment: If there can be nothing else on the line, `grep '^[ai]$' file` or `grep -Fx -e a -e i file`.

Comment: The file contains greek letters. The regex should show for example: beta, but it may NOT show for example iota, because this word contains both an i and an a

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve that with:

```
grep -E "^[^ai]*(a|i){1}[^ai]*$" testFile.txt
```

Comment: The problem is that this gives me a quiet large black space.

Comment: Can you provide a sample when it does not work properly? I've tested on [this](http://pastebin.com/Wkegi3Me) file, works good

Comment: The file contains greek letters. The regex should show for example: beta, but it may NOT show for example iota, because this word contains both an i and an a

Comment: My sample will pass `beta` (single `a`), but not `alfa` (`a` occurred twice in string) or `iota` (both `a` and `i`) - I've checked just now

Comment: Indeed, I tried with your file and then it works, thanks! I think there is a problem with the file itself.

Comment: The `{1}` is completely redundant. The `(a|i)` might as well be expressed with a character class `[ai]` in which case you don't need the `-E` option.

Comment: While I admit that I've missed a way to resolve an issue without extended regex, my sample still fit OP's question. Yet in the same time, despite your downvote, I thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an exclusive OR then try this:
`grep -E '^[^i]*a[^i]*$|^[^a]*i[^a]*$'`